# IP address validator using edittext

Tags: android, regex, validation, android-edittext, ip

I want the user to enter ip address in edittext and verify if it is valid. This is my code. How do I validate? I have referred to this link [Validation in EditText allow IP or web Url host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467690/validation-in-edittext-allow-ip-or-web-url-host/40887281) as well but not able to implement. Please help

```
 private static final String IPADDRESS_PATTERN =
        "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
                "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
                "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
                "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
if (ip_addr.isEmpty() ||!ip_addr.matches(IPADDRESS_PATTERN)) {
                    builder.setTitle("Something went wrong!!");
                    displayAlert("You have not entered valid IP Address");

}
}
}
```

Comment: yes I forgot to add. I have updated

Comment: Please show us which IPs are not matching, yet you expect them to match.

Comment: 192.168.0.103.. The input type of edittext is string. What should be the pattern?

Comment: [Here is your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r6Wk26/1), looks fine.